# AREF above operating voltage of the microcontroller

Tags: arduino, avr

I’m operating an ATMega32 at 3v3 through USB and a LDO.

Is it possible to connect the AREF pin directly to the USB voltage of 5V so that I can read voltages between 0 and 5V when reading from the analog pins?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: The microcontroller definitey can operate at 5V same applies to AREF it can operate under 5V, it is unclear to me if it can have a higher voltage than the one being fed through the VCC pins.

Comment: Indeed this information will be in the datasheet, but since it might be difficult to find I'll help a bit: The datasheet will state that the voltages at the uC's inputs/outputs **cannot exceed the voltage on the VDD pins**. The reason for this is the ESD protection diodes. As soon as the voltage at AREF becomes higher than VDD + 0.5 V the AREF's ESD diode will start conducting. If you want a 5 V input range either power the uC with 5 V **or** use a voltage divider to lower the input voltage to the ADC.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll use a voltage divider as it’s the best solution in my case.

Comment: To learn more about what issues the ESD diodes can cause, watch this EEVBlog video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yFh7Vv0Paw Making this and comment above an answer because, well it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed this information will be in the datasheet, but since it might be difficult to find I'll help a bit:

The datasheet will state that the voltages at the uC's inputs/outputs **cannot exceed the voltage on the VDD pins**.

The reason for this is the ESD protection diodes. As soon as the voltage at AREF becomes higher than VDD + 0.5 V the AREF's ESD diode will start conducting.

So if you connect 5 V to AREF, the VDD supply of the uC will be pulled up to about 4.4 V ! But you supplied 3.3 V via an LDO. Yes, then the LDO will do nothing.

If you want a 5 V input range either power the uC with 5 V

**or**

use a voltage divider to lower the input voltage to the ADC.

To learn more about what issues the ESD diodes can cause, [watch this EEVBlog video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yFh7Vv0Paw)